# Change application context from inside a WAR inside EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere

Is there a chance to shorten URL for accessing my servlet?
Current deployed URL is `server:port/WebApp/myservlet`.
I'd like to shorten it to `server:port/myservlet`

The servlet is located inside a WAR archive which is inside an EAR archive.

web.xml content inside WebApp.war/WEB-INF

```
<display-name>WebApp</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet code here:

```
@WebServlet("/*")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // some magic here
    }
}
```

P.S.: I need it to work on both JBoss and Websphere.

EDIT: 
My apologies, I forgot to mention that I can't change the context using `application.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change application context root from `/WebApp` to `/`, not the servlet mapping. The best way is to define it in the `application.xml` file  like this:

```
<application>
    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
    <module>    
        <web>
            <web-uri>WebApp.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

**UPDATE**
If you don't have `application.xml`, then you need proprietary descriptors.
**JBoss** - `jboss-web.xml` see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html)

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**WebSphere** - `ibm-web-ext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">
    <context-root uri="/"/>
</web-ext>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already found this solution on the JBoss site, but. I'm working on a small piece of code which is supposed to be a part of really big app. And there is no application.xml used and I can't go that way. Sorry I forgot to mention it. Otherwise you are absolutely right. +1

Comment: I'd like to figure out how to make it work on JBoss - configure web.xml, jboss-web.xml and the servlet annotation all together. I'll focuse on WAS afterwards.

Comment: @Kousalik See updated answer. You need proprietary descriptors. But I'd suggest to use `application.xml` as this is the portable way, and shouldn't be a big issue to add creation of that file to any build process you are using.

Comment: Hey Gas! thanks for update, you're idea is corerct.But it doesn't work this way. BUT it works the other way round! Setting the context root as /WebApp and my servlet mapping to "/". I'll accept your answer if you'll update it accordingly. Cheers

Comment: BTW I really can't take the application.xml way, as this is a big enterprise product, being customized for one particular scenario. Except it's not allowed, I'd probably cause more harm than good.